# Object oriented python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, object-oriented

I am starting my adventure with Python and object oriented programming.

I wrote a script for salting and hashing password. My main goal is practice with OOP, not cryptography. 
I know there is no error handling.

Wonder how improve my code it and make more object oriented. 
It would be nice if someone more experienced can take a look and give me some advice how to make it better.
Any help for newbie would be great!

**Description:**

The script is not really useful in real life.

1st part:
Hash and salt password and next encode to base64 with added salt (needed for future comparing hashes). Algorithm: base64( SHA256(password + salt) + salt)
Salt is X random bytes where X can be specify but by default it is 16.

2nd part (some kind of authorization):
Compare input hash (e.x. from database) with new created hash from input plain password.
New salt is created from  salt taken from input hash.

**Code:**

```py
import base64
import hashlib
import os


class Hashing(object):

    # base64( SHA256(password + salt) + salt)

    # generate new salt (default 16 bytes)
    def generate_new_salt(self, salt_ln=16):

        self.new_salt = os.urandom(salt_ln)

        print(f'new salt: {self.new_salt}')

        return self.new_salt

    # get salt from hash
    def get_old_salt(self, input_hash, salt_ln=16):

        self.old_salt = base64.b64decode(input_hash)[-salt_ln:]

        print(f'old salt: {self.old_salt}')

        return self.old_salt

    # compute hash using parameters
    def compute_hash(self, password, salt):

        self.salt = salt
        self.enc_password = password.encode()

        # hashing SHA256(password + salt)
        hash_object = hashlib.sha256(self.enc_password + salt)

        # add salt to hash and encode to base64
        hash_b64 = base64.b64encode(hash_object.digest() + salt)

        print(f'new_hash: {hash_b64}')
        return hash_b64

    # create hash from new or old salt
    def create_hash(self, password, salt_ln=16,old_salt=None):

        if old_salt:    #if old salt then use it
            self.salt = old_salt
        else:           #else generate new salt
            self.salt = Hashing().generate_new_salt(salt_ln)


        hash = Hashing().compute_hash(password, self.salt)

        return hash

    # compare input hash with created using salt get from input
    def compare_hashes(self, password, old_hash, salt_ln=16):

        self.enc_password = password.encode()

        #get salt from input hash
        self.old_salt = Hashing().get_old_salt(old_hash, salt_ln)

        #recreat input hash
        re_hash = Hashing().create_hash(password,salt_ln, self.old_salt)

        print(f'Compare: old_hash: {old_hash}')
        print(f'Compare: new_hash: {re_hash}')

        #compare
        if re_hash.decode() == old_hash.decode():
            return True
        else:
            return False



#code below is just for testing

NewSalt = Hashing().generate_new_salt()

Hash = Hashing().create_hash('pass')

OldSalt = Hashing().get_old_salt(Hash)

CompareHash = Hashing().compare_hashes('pass', Hash)

if CompareHash:
    print('HASHES THE SAME')
else:
    print('NOT THE SAME')

print(CompareHash)
```

**Questions:**

1. What is a real difference between these two? With and w/o **self.X** works

   ```py
   def generate_new_salt(self, salt_ln=16):
           self.new_salt = os.urandom(salt_ln)
           print(f'new salt: {self.new_salt}')
           return self.new_salt
   ```

   ```py
   def generate_new_salt(self, salt_ln=16):
       new_salt = os.urandom(salt_ln)
       print(f'new salt: {new_salt}')
       return new_salt
   ```
2. I have problem with passing default value of salt length, `salt_ln = 16`. For me it does not look nice when it is replicated in every method. Is there any way to do it more global?

Comment: Note that sha256 is not secure for passwords: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/how-secure-are-sha256-salt-hashes-for-password-storage

Comment: @markspace this script is just exercice with OOP, not cryptography. Ps. Fixed bug in code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Questions

1. `self` is the instance of whatever class the method is defined on.
   In your example the method is `generate_new_salt` which is defined on the `Hashing` class.

   When you use `my_hashing = Hashing()` you're creating an instance and binding it to the variable `my_hashing`. When you then call the method, via something like `my_hashing.generate_new_salt(...)` then `self` is the same as `my_hashing`. They both point to the same instance of `Hashing`.

   ```py
   >>> class Foo:
           def comp(self):
               return my_foo == self


   >>> my_foo = Foo()
   >>> my_foo.comp()
   True
   ```

   This means that `self.foo = ...` binds `...` to the instance. This allows you to then use `self.foo` to get the value, `...`, back at a later date. Without having to pass it as an argument. If you have no reason to use `self.foo` rather than just `foo`, then using `self.foo` is not a good idea.
2. This comes from two different but linked things.

   - You're trying to be *too helpful*. A lot of your code is not doing much, and is just calling other functions.

     This is a common problem when programming, and so I would recommend you follow the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). If you don't need the helper now, then you don't need it at all.
   - You're not really using objects to their potential. If you wrap all of your methods in `staticmethod` decorators then nothing will change. This highlights that you're not really following OOP. And it highlights you're barely using the features `class` provides.

Given the above points, it would be best to start over.

## Review

- It's normally recommended to not use `print`. There are exceptions, but in most cases you're better served either by just not having `print` or using `logging`.

  There is one exception, which is to interact with the user via the CLI. And in this case `Hashing` does not need to do that. Where you're testing needs it and so you should only have them below that comment "code below is just for testing".
- Inheriting from object, `Hashing(object)`, is redundant in Python 3.
- Rather than using an `if` to compare something and then `return` `True` and `False`. You can just return the comparison.

  ```py
  return re_hash.decode() == old_hash.decode()
  ```
- It would be best if the code below the comment "code below is just for testing" were in a function. This would mean that the global namespace isn't polluted with things that don't need to be there.
- It's best to use an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard. Since you only run the main function if you're testing, this will allow you to import the code without the testing code running.

## From the ground up

1. Merging both the hash and the salt into the encoding, "base64(hash + salt)", is a smart way to keep the hash and the salt together. However it would be clearer if you create a class that stores the hash and the salt independently.

   ```py
   class PasswordHash:
       def __init__(self, hash, salt):
           self.hash = hash
           self.salt = salt

   ph = PasswordHash(b'hash', b'salt')
   print(ph.hash)  # b'hash'
   print(ph.salt)  # b'salt'
   ```

   From here you should be able to see two things:

   - The method `get_old_salt` is now obsolete.
   - You no longer need to care about the salt length.
2. When you first define a class, after writing the `__init__`, you should ask yourself if the class will ever be printed. If it could be printed, then you should make at least one of these dunder methods, [double underscore method](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-special-method).

   - `__repr__` - Instructions on how to rebuild the method.
   - `__str__` - A human friendly interpretation of the class.

   In this case `__repr__` could make sense, but `__str__` doesn't.

   ```py
   def __repr__(self):
       return f'PasswordHash({self.hash}, {self.salt})'
   ```

   You should be able to see, `__repr__` outputs the exact text we used to make the instance.

   ```py
   >>> print(PasswordHash(b'hash', b'salt'))
   PasswordHash(b'hash', b'salt')
   ```
3. From here we need to think about how we should hash the password, since we don't want to store the password in plaintext. And so we can add `compute_hash` to `PasswordHash`, with 2 modifications.

   - I prefer the name `hash_password`, as it explains what it does, and what it does it on.
   - Secondly I would make it a `staticmethod`. This comes with a couple of reasons why:

     1. It allows us to create `PasswordHash` from a password easier.
     2. It allows for subclasses of `PasswordHash` to change the way the class hashes things.

   ```
   @staticmethod
   def hash_password(password, salt):
       hash = hashlib.sha256(password.encode() + salt)
       return base64.b64encode(hash.digest())
   ```

   Currently making a `PasswordHash` from a password is pretty ugly.

   ```py
   ph = PasswordHash(PasswordHash.hash_password(password, salt), salt)
   ```
4. Since the current interface for making a `PasswordHash` from a password is not the nicest. And is the standard way to use the class, we can make a class method to make it pretty.

   The reason this is a `classmethod` and not a standard method is because we need it to run before `__init__`. It is also a `classmethod` and not a `staticmethod` as we'll be using the first argument, `cls`, to instantiate the class.

   ```py
   @classmethod
   def from_password(cls, password, salt):
       return cls(cls.hash_password(password, salt), salt)
   ```

   Now making the `PasswordHash` from a password is really clean.

   ```py
   ph = PasswordHash.from_password('pass', salt)
   ```
5. We're almost at the end. The last thing to do is to add the spiritual child of `compare_hashes` to the class. Which is really simple since we have `self.salt` and `PasswordHash.hash_password`.

   ```py
   def compare(self, password):
       return self.hash == self.hash_password(password, self.salt)
   ```

Tying this all together you can get:

```py
import base64
import hashlib
import os


def new_salt(length=16):
    return os.urandom(length)


class PasswordHash:
    def __init__(self, hash, salt):
        self.hash = hash
        self.salt = salt

    @classmethod
    def from_password(cls, password, salt):
        return cls(cls.hash_password(password, salt), salt)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'PasswordHash({self.hash}, {self.salt})'

    @staticmethod
    def hash_password(password, salt):
        hash = hashlib.sha256(password.encode() + salt)
        return base64.b64encode(hash.digest())

    def compare(self, password):
        return self.hash == self.hash_password(password, self.salt)


def main():
    salt = new_salt()
    print('salt:', salt)
    hash = PasswordHash.from_password('pass', salt)
    print('PasswordHash:', hash)
    print('hash:', hash.hash)
    print('salt:', hash.salt)
    print('compare pass:', hash.compare('pass'))
    print('compare bar :', hash.compare('bar'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To make the comparison to be more OOP you could rename `compare` to the dunder method `__eq__`. And then you could use it via the `==` operator.

```py
print('compare pass:', hash == 'pass')
print('compare bar :', hash == 'bar')
```